# Spring Boot throws NoSuchMethodError org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty on external tomcat deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, nosuchmethoderror

I deloy a spring rest service as war file on external tomcat with spring-boot.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

The spring versions are managed by *spring-boot-starter-parent* in maven but always i get an exception which typical for incompatible spring version. I test with:

- spring-boot-starter-parent v*1.2.7.RELEASE* and v*1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT*
- tomcat v8.0.3 and 8.0.28

The strange is i also deployed as runnable jar file that is bug-free. I have also decompile war file and found [org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) in *\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE*.

I checked also maven debug output and find only one spring-core artifact with correct version (4.1.8.RELEASE).

It is possible that tomcat use spring-core also internal and there is a conflict?

**Exception in Tomcat logfile by deployment:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 45 more
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.cherrypit</groupId>
        <artifactId>lisa</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
```

Comment: Consider adding <version>${spring.version}</version> to your Spring dependencies.

Comment: ah yes! You're correct.  Its a spring class method :)

Comment: @JustinKSU if i add spring.version i become this warnung: `This expression evaluates to 4.1.8.RELEASE The property is defined in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.7.RELEASE`

Comment: @JustinKSU i get the same exception with <version>${spring.version}</version>

Comment: If you get a NoSuchMethod, it is very likely that this class is loaded already in a different version. Best way to find out is to check the dependencies like: `mvn dependency:tree > c:\dep.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. I would have also add spring-android-core in my project shared library *lisa*.

> Dont use **spring-android-core** and **spring-core** in classpath.